# Managing Software Sources

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04.

I cannot add or remove repositories neither by using **Software Sources** menu item (which usually crashes) nor by using Synaptic Package Manager via **Settings > Repositories** option.
This is possibly due to having installed 'Debian Package Search' from `*buntu-software-center`, after which I ran `sudo apt-file update`. Should I run `sudo apt-file purge` ? This sounds drastic!

I can manage repositories via `sudo add-apt-repository`.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem. Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again. Also, you can add/remove repositories using other ways as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

You can add or remove sources manually.

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add or remove the source(s).

Shortcut to add sources `echo <source> >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

After adding or deleting sources you should run `apt-get updade && apt-get upgrade`
More information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).